# WebStorm does not recognize my custom Angular.js directives

Tags: angular, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am creating custom Angular.js directives but WebStorm 2017.1.2 does not recognize them:

[image]

My WebStorm JavaScript library settings are like this:

[image]

And Angular.js plugins are installed.

I notice now a situation about this problem. If I create a new project and new directives, WebStorm recognizes custom directives. But I am working on a  large project and custom directives are not recognized there.

Is there special case for directives?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `angular.js` file (debug version, uncompressed!) in your project? Normally it's enough to get Angular directives/methods recognized. See http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/, '*Include angular.js in Your Project*' section

Note that angular typescript stubs (`angular-Definitely typed`, etc.) won't work here, you need `angular.js` to enable AngularJS support

Comment: Yes I am using angular.js file not angular.min.js

Comment: are you sure it's available in your project directory (and not excluded)? If yes, please provide the project - it seems to be the only way to see what's wrong (as, according to you, similar directives work fine in another project)

Comment: Yes it is under the folder `applicaiton/js/vendor/angular/angular.js`

Comment: make sure that this folder is not marked as excluded